# Finding where my local Android repo working copy was derived from

Tags: android, git, repository

After I have downloaded a gingerbread system build using the following commands, how do I later come back and find which Android tag it was derived from?

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b gingerbread
repo sync
```

NOTE: The 'gingerbread' tag above seems to be a 'rolling' tag that moves as and when google releases a new gingerbread build. 
I would like to find out the tag with the release number in, e.g: android-2.3.1_r1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gingerbread` is indeed a "rolling tag", which is what we usually call a branch. :)

The `gingerbread` branch will contain the latest gingerbread release + patches received accecpted through the [AOSP](http://source.android.com/) (usually called gingerbread+AOSP).

Running the command `git describe` should provide you with the latest tag your current commit is based on:

```
$ git describe
android-2.3.3_r1a-49-gaa0ddd0
```

However you cannot do this for the entire Andorid repo, only for the individual git repositories. Fortunately they are all tagged with the same tag for each release, such as `android-2.3.3_rx`.

Run:

```
$ repo forall -c "pwd; git describe"
```

to get the latest tag for all the repositories in the Android repo hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The repo tool keeps track of the `-u` and `-b` option arguments in the `.repo/manifests` git repo.

To find out the `-u` option argument, see the `origin` remote in `.repo/manifests`:

```
  (cd .repo/manifests; git remote -v)
```

Then look for for the url.

To find out the `-b` option argument, see what branch the local `default` branch tracks:

```
  (cd .repo/manifests; git config branch.default.merge)
```

Note that the branch that you specify to `repo init` with `-b` is the branch in the manifest git repo.  It is the `manifest.xml` that then defines the branch or commit for each individual projects.

Perhaps more obviously, the `-m` option defines the file that `.repo/manifest.xml` points to.